# Is there a way to create a message box that is triggered when a data validation error occurs in a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I need a data validation rule that checks to see whether a date value between 01/01/2000 and 01/01/2020 is entered.

I can do this with Excel's built in data validation tool. However, the "alert" message box is problematic. The alert message box always has a "Cancel" button. If a user clicks the "Cancel" button, the cell's contents are deleted. This deletion cannot be undone.

I need a message box that only has a "Retry" option. Maybe also the option to "quit" cell editing without changing the cell's original contents.

So I need a code that "listens" for a data validation error and then prompts a message box to appear. What would this code look like in VBA?

That way, I can disable the alert box in excel's data validation tool. And only trigger my customized message box.

Comment: You could handle the issue in the `worksheet_change` event.  Your main issue may be that macros cannot be run when a cell is in edit mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the validation event triggers and you click Retry, the cell's contents get selected so you can edit it. I have not found a way to do that in VBA. The below can get you started, it is the validation you mention and messages, if the validation fails, it will activate/select the Cell for the user to Edit but this will not stop the user from moving along and not fixing the issue. This leaves you in the same spot as before, however this is the way to validate cell values outside of the Built in Validation tool and can get you on setting up a desired outcome.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim dStart As Date, dEnd As Date
    Dim targetDate As Date
    dStart = #1/1/2000#
    dEnd = #1/1/2020#
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A10")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cel In Target
            If IsDate(cel.Value) Then
                targetDate = cel.Value
                If targetDate < dStart Or targetDate > dEnd Then
                    MsgBox "Wrong Date, must be between 1/1/2000 and 1/1/2022"
                    Target.Select
                    Target.Activate
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox "Wrong Input, must be a date"
                Target.Select
                Target.Activate
            End If
        Next cel
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: hi, rookie question -- I've added this code to a worksheet module but it won't run? there's nothing else in the worksheet module. shouldn't this affect my cells as soon as I add the code? or am I missing something?

Comment: To a Module or to THE Worksheet Module. There is a difference. You must add this to THE Worksheet one, do not create a Module. Also for example if you add it to the Sheet1 Module it will only work when on Sheet1. Also the code above shows a Range of "A2 to A10" it will only trigger for those Cells. Additionally, depending on your settings sometimes you must save the workbook as xlsm and re open it because the new workbook may have by default Macros Disabled.

Comment: it turned out to be an issue with the security settings on my file... as I was correctly adding the code to the worksheet module. thank you for the lead.

Comment: also may I suggest an edit to your answer before I mark it as correct? I used your answer but with some modifications. To set start and end dates, I had to format as follows... dtStart = #1/1/2000#. so I declared this variable and then called dtStart and dtEnd as my start-end dates. you were also incredibly helpful so thank you.

Comment: no need to update the code to mark it as answered. But I added the date variables in case that makes it better for you.